# Django 3.0.5 with mod_wsgi: AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute '_resource_closers'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm getting an error when I deploy Django 3.0.5 under `mod_wsgi`: `AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute '_resource_closers'`. I'm running:

- Python: 3.6.8
- Django: 3.0.5
- Apache: 2.4.6
- mod_wsgi: 4.6.2

Here's the basics of the view causing the error; nothing too exotic (I've simplified the code around `meetings_struct`):

```py
class MeetingsAPIView(MeetingsBaseView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        meetings = self.get_meetings()
        meetings_struct = []

        for meeting in meetings:
            meetings_struct.append({
                "id": meeting.id,
                "name": meeting.title,
                "slug": meeting.slug,
            })

        return HttpResponse(meetings_struct, content_type="application/json")
```

If I activate the `venv` and use `runserver` manually on the server on port 80, the same view does not give an error. When the same code and `venv` are running under Apache, here's the error from Apache's logs:

```
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.683980 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397] mod_wsgi (pid=4154): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/django/sites/mysite-prod/config/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.684834 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.684891 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397]   File "/var/django/sites/mysite-prod/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.684903 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.684925 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397]   File "/var/django/sites/mysite-prod/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 76, in get_response
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.684933 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397]     response._resource_closers.append(request.close)
[Sat Apr 18 16:11:30.684964 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4154] [remote 100.19.146.139:54397] AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute '_resource_closers'
```

I've rolled back to a previous version that works, running Django 2.2; the rest of the stack is the same. This one has me puzzled, as using the same deployed code with the same `venv` that Apache is configured to use works fine under `runserver`, but errors with `mod_wsgi`.

I've tried stopping and starting Apache, running the publish process again for a fresh `venv` and code base, and even rebooting the server. The same error occurs, but only under Apache / mod_wsgi.

Any ideas? I'm puzzled!

Comment: I have the same problem using Django 3.0.6, Python 3.8.2, and Gunicorn. Are you using sentry-sdk? It seems that in my case the problem is caused by Sentry integration.

Comment: I'm not, unfortunately. It's a pretty vanilla install - Django with Wagtail, with a few JSON endpoints for a ReactJS app. I still haven't found a solution - I was in the process of switching to Gunicorn, since I'd been meaning to move in that direction anyway. Are you on the latest/greatest Gunicorn? Wondering if this is async related.

Comment: Had the same issue eariler today and for me it turned out the be a problem with caching the view response. Purged the memcache and it started working.

Comment: I'm using the latest Gunicorn (20.0.4) and in my opinion, this is not async related. To solve this problem, I had to downgrade to Django 2.2.12. (LTS).

Comment: @illagrenan Have you solved the issue with Sentry? It seems in my case also the problem is caused by Sentry: `File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\django\__init__.py", line 350, in sentry_patched_get_response`. Just updated to Django 3.1.5 from 2.2.3.

Comment: @illagrenan Actually clearing caches solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clear/purge/flush your server's cache (e.g. Memcache or Redis).